# converting string to ascii and error assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c

I am running the following code and I want to take the ASCII code of each character of the string individually. But I get the error: `assignment to expression with array type` in the line where I use `atoi`. What I want to take is the ASCII code of `I`, of `p`, of space and so on. How can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int a_buf[100];
char buf[100], def_name[] = "Ip Quoridor";
char *cmd, *par;
int length, i, j;
fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
length = strlen(buf);
a_buf = atoi(buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `atoi`, just print the character values directly like this

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot assign to an array in [c](/questions/tagged/c), but even if you could this

```
a_buf = atoi(buf);
```

doesn't make sense. Because `atoi()` returns an `int` and you are attempting to assign an integer to an array. The `atoi()` function takes a string of characters and converts it to the decimal value they represent, for example

```
int decimal = atoi("121");
```

will assign `121` to `decimal`.

You don't need to assign the ascii value to anything, because the values in the `buf` array *are the ascii values of the characters* `fgets()` just read.

What you should do is check `fgets()` return value before trying to access `buf`, like this

```
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; ((buffer[i] != '\n') && (buffer[i] != '\0')) ; ++i)
    {
        printf("The ascii value of `%c' is `%d'\n", buffer[i], buffer[i]);
    }
}
```